# oracle ratio_to_report

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone show how to calculate over `ratio_to_report` function from field Price to take out 2 percentage of the Price.

```
ratio_to_report(price) over () from table .
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Can you add some example data and expected output?

Comment: I want from every price to calculate 2 percent ..

Comment: Show sample data and expected output.

Comment: Expected output is percentage/price * 100 

https://imgur.com/a/XCliuRK

Comment: Yeah, still have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @eaolson To calculate 2 % of price column ... simple as that .

Comment: Isn't that `price * .02`? What does this have to do with [`ratio_to_report`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RATIO_TO_REPORT.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
SELECT 0.02 * price FROM table
```

No `OVER` clause needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this: 100%-2% = 98% = 0.98

Code:

```
SELECT 0.98 * price FROM table
```